# How to create lisp for AutoCAD that will allow you to place hatches on top of already created ones, and without intersections?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

Is it possible to create lisp code for AutoCAD that will allow us to place a hatch on top of another? In AutoCAD, when two or more hatches are placed in one area, they all intersect with each other, creating some kind of incomprehensible mess.

It would be interesting and useful to create a lisp that allows you to place hatches on top of each other, so that the first hatch does not appear inside the second hatch, but appears under it. If you have any ideas on how to implement this, please answer me.

The picture shows an example of how hatching works now and what result I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it may not be possible. But I have some workaround.
First and the most important question You have to answar is: Do You have to do it by LISP, or maybe result by just few clicks is acceptable.
To have it by clicks You shoud:

1. Create the shape of segment which must overlay others as `polyline`.
2. Create a `wipeout` based of shape ( like a drop on Your example )
3. Create `block` containing `wipeout`
4. Use command `SUPERCHATCH` to fill Your area by block.
5. commad `DrawOrder` helps You to set superhatch topmost.

In fact points 1-3,5 You can do by LISP, but the problem starts with using `SuperHatch` by lisp. I'm using ZWCAD where `SuperHatch` is not avaliable in dialogless mode. I can't test on AutoCAD. Also creating superhatch by LISP may be complicated and maybe not necessary if using few commands wouldb be acceptable.