How to add hatches in AutoCAD so that they overlap each other?
I am using the Python language and the win32com.client library to add hatches to a drawing.
Here is the code that implements the creation of hatchings:
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
acadModel = acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace 

def APoint(x, y, z = 0):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8, (x, y, z))

def ADouble(xyz):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8, (xyz))

def variants(object):
    return win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_DISPATCH, (object))

out_loop = [acadModel.AddPolyline(ADouble([0,0,0,1000,0,0,1000,1000,0,0,1000,0,0,0,0]))]

hatch = acadModel.AddHatch(0, "HEX", True)
hatch.PatternScale = 20
hatch.AppendOuterLoop(variants(out_loop))
hatch.Evaluate()

hatch = acadModel.AddHatch(0, "ANSI31", True)
hatch.PatternScale = 10
hatch.AppendOuterLoop(variants(out_loop))
hatch.Evaluate()

The task is to find a solution to overlapping hatches on each other, which can be implemented using python. The desired result is shown on the right side of the picture.

I can do this task manually in autocad using the Explode command to the first hatch and then add a second hatch. But I need to implement this using Python.
I was also advised a method where WipeOut and SuperHatch are used, but I still haven't figured out how to implement this in code. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77905739/23389658)
Maybe it need to modify the autocad scripts, with lisp or Autolisp. I don't know.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution using ActiveX (COM), mainly because Hatch doesn't have an explode method. I suggest using PyRx - Python wrapper over Object ARX.
In a nutshell:

create a HEX hatch,
explode into single lines,
connect the lines into hexagons,
add target hatching by cutting out hexagons.

import traceback
from itertools import pairwise
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

import numpy as np
import shapely
from pyrx_imp import Db, Ge
from shapely.ops import linemerge


def PyRxCmd_doit():
    try:
        
        # HEX hatch
        hex_hatch = Db.Hatch()
        hex_hatch.setDatabaseDefaults()
        hex_hatch.setPattern(Db.HatchPatternType.kPreDefined, "HEX")

        outer_edges = (
            ((0.0, 0.0), (100.0, 0.0)),
            ((100.0, 0.0), (100.0, 100.0)),
            ((100.0, 100.0), (0.0, 100.0)),
            ((0.0, 100.0), (0.0, 0.0)),
        )

        outer_segments = [
            Ge.LineSeg2d(Ge.Point2d(p1), Ge.Point2d(p2)) for p1, p2 in outer_edges
        ]

        hex_hatch.appendLoopEdges(
            Db.HatchLoopType.kExternal,
            outer_segments,
            [Db.HatchEdgeType.kLine for _ in outer_segments],
        )
        hex_hatch.evaluateHatch()

        # explode hatch and get single lines
        hex_lines_ents = hex_hatch.explode()
        hex_lines = [Db.Line.cast(ent) for ent in hex_lines_ents]

        # connect individual lines in a "polyline" so that you can 
        # create loops for cutting the target hatch; round the coordinates 
        # so that the lines connect properly
        hex_lines_points = [
            (
                np.round(i.startPoint().toTuple()[:2], 6),
                np.round(i.endPoint().toTuple()[:2], 6),
            )
            for i in hex_lines
        ]

        plines = get_plines(hex_lines_points)  # get_plines below

        # Target hatch
        hatch = Db.Hatch()
        hatch.setPattern(Db.HatchPatternType.kPreDefined, "ANSI31")

        hatch.appendLoopEdges(
            Db.HatchLoopType.kExternal,
            outer_segments,
            [Db.HatchEdgeType.kLine for _ in outer_edges],
        )

        for pline in plines:  # hex plines
            
            # create a list of segments that make up the polylines of one hexagon
            line_segments = [
                Ge.LineSeg2d(Ge.Point2d(p1), Ge.Point2d(p2))
                for p1, p2 in pairwise(pline)
            ]
            hatch.appendLoopEdges(
                Db.HatchLoopType.kDefault,
                line_segments,
                [Db.HatchEdgeType.kLine for _ in line_segments],
            )

        hatch.evaluateHatch()

        db = Db.HostApplicationServices().workingDatabase()
        model = Db.BlockTableRecord(db.modelSpaceId(), Db.OpenMode.kForWrite)
        model.appendAcDbEntity(hatch)  # add hatch to the model
        model.appendAcDbEntities(hex_lines)  # add hexagon lines if needed too
        model.close()
        
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()


Point_T = Tuple[float, float]

def get_plines(
    line_points: Iterable[Tuple[Point_T, Point_T]]
) -> Iterable[Iterable[Point_T]]:
    line_strings = linemerge(line_points)
    if isinstance(line_strings, shapely.LineString):
        line_strings = (line_strings,)
    elif isinstance(line_strings, shapely.MultiLineString):
        pass
    else:
        raise TypeError
    for line_string in line_strings.geoms:
        ch = line_string.convex_hull
        if isinstance(ch, shapely.Polygon):
            yield ch.exterior.coords

Problems to solve
The algorithm requires refinement at the hatch outer edge; the beginning and end of a polyline that is part of a hexagon are connected straight ahead instead of along the outer hatch outline; I suggest playing with shapely - create a HEX hatch whose outline is larger than the target hatch, and cut the polylines (get_plines() above) of this hatch from the polygon (shapely.Polygon) of the target hatch.

PyRx

Install the latest release,
Start AutoCAD and allow the PyRx.arx add-in to load,
From the command line, run the PYLOAD command and select the python module with your code,
Invoke the DOIT command (PyRxCmd_doit).

PyRx allows user interaction, for the user to specify the external hatch outline, use the Ed module (from pyrx_imp import Ed)
You can also use ActiveX (Autocad Object Model) with PyRx, check it out:
from pyrx_impx import Ax

doc = Ax.getDbx()  # same as acad.ActiveDocument


Why are pyrx and PyRxDebug showing up as undiscovered libraries in vscode? And when I run the DOIT command, I get an error - https://pastebin.com/263bwv6e.

My python code creates hatches in different areas. There can be more than one hatch  in one area. How do I create each new hatch so that its islands are elements of previous hatches?
Here is my code - https://pastebin.com/n36JBs2W
If needed - let's open a chat room for discussion. I will be very happy to have your help

I edited the answer, there was an error in hex_lines_points, I changed generator comprehension to list comprehension

undiscovered libraries - check this https://github.com/CEXT-Dan/PyRx/issues/3

Thanks, check my comment above please

Please show sample data and the expected effect as well as the current code (entire)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
